# Create <span> element with markdown (kramdown)

Tags: markdown, html

Is it possible to create a span element with markdown? I'm using the Kramdown converter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Markdown syntax spec/documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), you should be able to use a plain HTML `<span>` element. Additionally, the [Kramdown documentation](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#html-spans) has an entire section on using HTML elements in general, and `<span>` in particular.

From Kramdown's docs:

> HTML tags cannot only be used on the block-level but also on the
> span-level. Span-level HTML tags can only be used inside one
> block-level element, it is not possible to use a start tag in one
> block level element and the end tag in another. Note that only correct
> XHTML is supported! This means that you have to use, for example, `<br/>`
> instead of `<br>` (although kramdown tries to fix such errors if
> possible).
>
> By default, kramdown parses kramdown syntax inside span HTML tags.
> However, this behaviour can be configured with the parse_span_html
> option. If this is set to true, then syntax parsing in HTML spans is
> enabled, if it is set to false, parsing is disabled. It is also
> possible to enable/disable syntax parsing on a tag per tag basis using
> the markdown attribute:
>
> - If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="0", then no parsing (except parsing of HTML span tags) is done inside that HTML tag.
> - If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="1", then the content of the tag is parsed as span level elements.
> - If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="block", then a warning is issued because HTML spans cannot contain block-level elements and
>   the attribute is ignored.
> - If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="span", then the content of the tag is parsed as span level elements.

Comment: thanks, I know I can insert plain HTML, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. I thought there is a syntax for creating a span, like there is one for h1 -> # h1

Comment: From what I gather from the docs, no. Markdown is simply a subset of HTML that's been converted to allow for the source to be viewed and understood by humans. Generally speaking, only the "actually semantic" elements (Hn, p, emphasis, bold, lists, etc.) are converted. Spans and divs are arbitrary containers, and so have no real semantic meaning, and therefore no use in basic Markdown.

Comment: Pandoc markdown now does this (at least via adding CSS styling, with `[some text]{.aclass}` rendering as `<span class="aclass">some text</span>`). Waiting for it to appear in kramdown.

Answer (score -1):

I just use a [markdown span element.](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#span)

Comment: i know this is an old thread, can you provide an example of how you achieved this, if you remember?

Comment: The sub heading at the above link does say `SPANS`, but specifically it describes links, not `<span></span>` tags.