# styled <span> inside markdown table

Tags: html, html-table, markdown

I need to generate a markdown table with one of the columns that is style using a span. The span should look like this:

[image: span]

However, when I add it inside the markdown, the styling is ignored (I think).
How to fix this?

My attempt here:

```
**Team**|**Build status**|**Coverage status**|**Coverage details**|**Contribution rate**    
-----|-----|-----|-----|----
[W09-C1](https://github.com/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C1/main/blob/master/docs/AboutUs.md)|[![Unknown](https://travis-ci.org/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C1/main.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C1/main)|[![Unknown](https://coveralls.io/repos/github/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C1/main/badge.svg?branch=master)](https://coveralls.io/github/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C1/main?branch=master)|<span style="display:inline-block; text-align: center; width:143px;  background: #50FC00; border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px; white-space:nowrap;">1435</span><span style="display:inline-block; text-align: center; width:47px;  background: #FC5000; border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; white-space:nowrap;">476</span><span style="display:inline-block; text-align: center; width:172.2px;  background: #A900A9; border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;  white-space:nowrap;">1722</span>|[Contribution rate](https://github.com/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C1/main/graphs/contributors?from=2016-09-30&to=2016-11-08&type=c)
[W09-C2](https://github.com/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C2/main/blob/master/docs/AboutUs.md)|[![Unknown](https://travis-ci.org/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C2/main.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C2/main)|[![Unknown](https://coveralls.io/repos/github/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C2/main/badge.svg?branch=master)](https://coveralls.io/github/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C2/main?branch=master)|<span style="display:inline-block; text-align: center; width:242px;  background: #50FC00; border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px; white-space:nowrap;">2424</span><span style="display:inline-block; text-align: center; width:31px;  background: #FC5000; border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; white-space:nowrap;">314</span><span style="display:inline-block; text-align: center; width:290.88px;  background: #A900A9; border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;  white-space:nowrap;">2908</span>|[Contribution rate](https://github.com/CS2103AUG2016-W09-C2/main/graphs/contributors?from=2016-09-30&to=2016-11-08&type=c)
```

What I get:

[image]

Comment: If you create the table using HTML, instead of Markdown, does the same problem occur (assuming that the Markdown implementation allows the use of HTML mark-up to create a table)?

Comment: This post may helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685874/create-span-element-with-markdown-kramdown

Comment: @Soliyappan that post just says "you can use span" i started my attempt from there, but was unsuccessful

Comment: @DavidThomas this markdown is to be rendered by GitHub; I don't think it works well. The first screenshot I have put is using HTML instead of markdown.

Answer (score 2):

Official [syntax rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state:

> Markdown’s syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used as a format for writing for the web.
>
> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. The idea is not to create a syntax that makes it easier to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert. The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a publishing format; Markdown is a writing format. Thus, ***Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text***.
>
> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself.

As it is not a "publishing format," providing a way to style your text is out-of-scope for Markdown. That said, it is not impossible as you can include raw HTML (and HTML is a publishing format). For example, the following Markdown text:

```
Some Markdown text with <span style="color:blue">some *blue* text</span>.
```

Would result in the following HTML:

```
<p>Some Markdown text with <span style="color:blue">some <em>blue</em> text</span>.</p>
```

Now, StackOverflow (and probably GitHub) will strip the raw HTML out (as a security measure) so you loose the style here, but it should work on any standard Markdown implementation.

Comment: @Anastasia I suspect the last line in your response to be true. Else, if you see the code snippet, I use raw HTML for the span.